# Removable USB Drive disappears from "FILES" list when closed. Can not unmount

Tags: usb, unmount

Ubuntu 18.04.  Can use the USB memory stick but, it disappears from any list (anywhere) so I can not "Eject" it.

The stick keeps getting corrupted, and, I can not find any help from the OS at all.  It is like information is minimized and stuff is hidden (just like Microsoft does with Windows)!  But, as I am not informed about what this OS is supposed to do, perhaps I'm doing something wrong..  I want to close and unmount the stick!  It seems, there should be a routine that checks for open storage devices and unmount them at power-down. The OS does not do it.
How do I `Eject` / `unmount` a drive that I cannot find in `FILES`?

Answer (score 0):

Plug in the USB drive to an available port.

then Run the following command as sudo in your Terminal application in order to check the available storage devices on your system and the file system they are using:

$ sudo fdisk -l

Your USB device will usually be listed at the end of the output mostly as sdb-(number). In our case it is listed as sdb1, running a FAT32 file system.

Create a mount point for your USB device through the following command:

Syntax:

$ sudo mkdir /media/[mountPointName]

Note: The name of your mount point can not include spaces; you can seperate the words through an underscore ‘_’.

to mount the USB storage device to the mount point that we created. We will use the following command in order to mount a FAT32 device:

$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/USB -o [securityoption]

the security option is needed and allows you to give/gain access to the USB by specifying one of the following values for permission;

uid=1000

gid=1000

Utf8

dmask=027

fmask=137

For NTFS, use the following command:

$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/USB

Your USB has now been mounted. You can access it through your media folder.

Comment: This stuff is "band-aid".  The Ubuntu 18.04 is failure!  FIX IT!